# Navigation property in a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I'm currently learning interfaces and repository pattern and have difficulties with CRUD operations in my simple project.

I have domain class "VehicleMake"

```
public class VehicleMake
{
    public VehicleMake()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VehicleModel> VehicleModels { get; set; }
}
```

and a domain class "VehicleModel"

```
public class VehicleModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int VehicleMakeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual VehicleMake VehicleMake { get; set; }
}
```

I also have an Interface "IVehicleRepository"

```
  public interface IVehicleRepository
{
    void Add(VehicleMake vehicleMake);

    IEnumerable<VehicleMake> AllMakes { get; }
    IEnumerable<VehicleModel> AllModels { get; }
}
```

and a class "VehicleRepository" which implements that interface

```
 public class VehicleRepository : IVehicleRepository
{
    private readonly VehicleDbContext _context;

    public VehicleRepository(VehicleDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Add(VehicleMake vehicleMake)
    {
        _context.VehicleMakes.Add(vehicleMake);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IEnumerable<VehicleMake> AllMakes => _context.VehicleMakes;
    public IEnumerable<VehicleModel> AllModels => _context.VehicleModels;
}
```

My DbContext class is following

```
public class VehicleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public VehicleDbContext() : base("VehicleDbContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<VehicleMake> VehicleMakes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VehicleModel> VehicleModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }

}
```

My "VehicleMakeViewModel" is following

```
public class VehicleMakeViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Vehicle Make Number")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Vehicle Make Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and my "VehicleModelViewModel" is following

```
  public class VehicleModelViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Vehicle Model Number")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Vehicle Model Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Vehicle Make Id")]
    public int VehicleMakeId { get; set; }
}
```

I have "VehicleMakeController"

```
 public class VehicleMakeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IVehicleRepository _vehicleRepository;

    public VehicleMakeController()
    {
        _vehicleRepository = new VehicleRepository(new VehicleDbContext());
    }

    // GET: VehicleMake
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_vehicleRepository.AllMakes);
    }

    public ActionResult CreateVehicleMake()
    {
        return View(new VehicleMakeViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateVehicleMake(VehicleMakeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var vehicleMake = new VehicleMake();
            UpdateVehicleMake(vehicleMake, viewModel);
            _vehicleService.Add(vehicleMake);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    private void UpdateVehicleMake(VehicleMake vehicleMake, VehicleMakeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        vehicleMake.Id = viewModel.Id;
        vehicleMake.Name = viewModel.Name;
    }
}
```

and a "VehicleModelController

```
 public class VehicleModelController : Controller
{

    private readonly IVehicleRepository _vehicleRepository;

    public VehicleModelController()
    {
        _vehicleRepository = new VehicleRepository(new VehicleDbContext());
    }

    // GET: VehicleModel
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_vehicleRepository.AllModels);
    }


}
```

As you can see in my "VehicleMakeController" I have methods for adding of new Vehicle Makes "CreateVehicleMake". Problem is that I don't know how to do that in my "VehicleModelController" for vehicle models. When the user wants to add a new vehicle model he should enter a name of the new vehicle model in the text box and then he should in the dropdown list select the vehicle make that belongs to that vehicle model. I don't know how to implement this with repository pattern and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new property to `VehicleModelViewModel` class to hold the list of available options for the vehicle make dropdown.

```
public class VehicleModelViewModel
{
   public List<SelectListItem> Makes { set;get;}

   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "Vehicle Model Name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "Vehicle Make Id")]  
   public int VehicleMakeId { get; set; } 
}
```

Now in your GET action for the create screen, create an object of this view model, load the `Makes` property from the list of Makes

```
public class VehicleModelController : Controller
{    
    private readonly IVehicleRepository _vehicleRepository;    
    public VehicleModelController()
    {
        _vehicleRepository = new VehicleRepository(new VehicleDbContext());
    }    

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var vm=new VehicleModelViewModel();
        vm.Makes = GetMakeOptions();
        return View(vm);
    }
    private List<SelectListeItem> GetMakeOptions()
    {
      return this._vehicleRepository.AllMakes
                 .Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Value=x.Id.ToString(), 
                                                 Text=x.Name})
                 .ToList();
    }  
}
```

Now in your view, which is strongly typed to your view model, we will use the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method to generate the SELECT element

```
@model VehicleViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.LabelFor(s=>s.Name)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s=>s.Name)

   @Html.LabelFor(s=>s.MakeId)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.VehicleMakeId , Model.Makes)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s=>s.VehicleMakeId)

   <input type="submit" />
}
```

This will render the view with the SELECT element inside the form. Make sure you have an HttpPost Create action method in the controller which handles the form submit and saves the data back to your table

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(VehicleViewModel model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     var e = new VehicleModel { Name = model.Name, VehicleMakeId = model.VehicleMakeId };
     _vehicleRepository.Add(e);
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  model.Makes=GetMakes();
  return View(model);
}
```